# New routes with NextJS

Tags: firebase, routes, next.js, next.js13

I have a NextJS app on Firebase working basically the way I want up to now.

I can access it using a URL like: https://myownthing.web.app

Here is what I want to do next, to create a new route that I will access with:
https://myownthing.web.app/Special

The app file system is now structured like this:

```
-> myownthing
    -> next.config.js
    -> firebase.json
    -> .....
    -> app
        -> page.tsx
        -> layout.tsx
        -> .....
```

How can I create this new route that I need?

I searched for "nextjs routing" and tried a few things, like creating a new directory under app, but at this point without much success.

Some guidance would be welcome.

Comment: You could just create a `Special` folder inside `app`. And in it, add a `page.tsx`.

Comment: Yes, I tried that a second time and it finally worked. At least locally; that is after running "npm run dev" and then checking on "http://localhost:3000/Special". But for some reason that I ignore, it does not work on the server side. Pointing the browser to "https://myownthing.web.app/Special" gives this error: "404 This page could not be found." Of course I first ran "npm run build" and "firebase deploy --only hosting".